# What is the purpose of the HTTP response status code 226?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

Does someone ever use `HttpStatus.IM_USED` (226 - IM Used), and in which case or situation?

Comment: The [RFC for this status code](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3229#section-10.4.1) does a decent job of illustrating what purpose it actually serves.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](https://evertpot.com/http/226-im-used) does a much better job of explaining the purpose of this response status code. Basically, there is a feature called **Delta encoding in HTTP** that an HTTP server might support. If so, then it will be possible for the client to request changes to a resource that it has already cached instead of requesting the whole resource again.

To request the feature, the client request must have an `A-IM` header specifying what Instance Manipulation types it supports, the values of which [are listed](https://www.iana.org/assignments/inst-man-values/inst-man-values.xhtml). If the server supports this feature, it will respond with the 226 status code and the body of the diff. Otherwise, it will respond with status 200 and the whole resource.